# Getting undefined when using "var" instead of "let" with Object.assign()

Tags: javascript

```
var name = {
  nameValue: 'John'
};
console.log(name.nameValue);  // undefined
var surname = {
  surnameValue: 'Doe'
};
Object.assign(name, surname);
console.log(name.surnameValue); // undefined
```

I am getting undefined when using var but everything is working good with let and
I am running this code on jsbin.com

Answer (score 5):

Global scope (i.e. `window` in this case) already has a property `name`. You'll need to either create a new scope by wrapping your code with a function. Or use block scoped variable declaration `let`

```js
console.log(typeof name); // string

var name = {
  nameValue: 'John'
};
console.log(name.nameValue); // undefined
var surname = {
  surnameValue: 'Doe'
};
Object.assign(name, surname);
console.log(name.surnameValue); // undefined

function run() {
  var name = {
    nameValue: 'John'
  };
  console.log(name.nameValue); // John
  var surname = {
    surnameValue: 'Doe'
  };
  Object.assign(name, surname);
  console.log(name.surnameValue); // Doe
}

run();
```

Comment: You did show him how to create a variable inside a different context, but I think the question was more about why is it not working.

Comment: @fingeron That's why there is the first sentence in my question explaining **why** it is not working as is.

Comment: If I replace "var" with "let" everything is working correctly. Why is this happening? I understood that "name" is already a property.

Comment: @AmritanshuRai `let` is block scoped https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

Because 'name' is existed in window, you can use other name of variable

```
var name0 = {
  nameValue: 'John'
};
console.log(name0.nameValue);
```

Comment: It's also working when I replace var with let. why is this happening?

Comment: @Amritanshu Rai, the voted answer shows.When you use var,browser default global scope is window.But when you use let,there is no global scope,but you have a space block scope

Answer (score 0):

[(Window.)name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a specific value of the global `window` object that **can be used** (but pretty uncommon) for setting forms and hyperlinks targets.

The `name` property is not read only but is limited to the primitive type `string`. Therefore, any value that you assign to `window.name` will turn into a string.

This is essentially why you got `undefined` when used `name.nameValue`. `name` is not an object.

```
var name = { hello: "world!" };
console.log(name + ' - ' + name.hello); // "[object Object] - undefined"
var name = "Hello World!"
console.log(name); // "Hello World!";
```

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the variable `name` in the global scope in `window` object. When you set the value of name in window object, its `get` method will call the `toString` method.

As specified in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

```
var name = {first:"Vignesh"};
console.log(name); //(1)
console.log(name.first); //(2)
```

(1) will give the value `[object Object]` as string instead of `{first: "Vignesh"}`.

(2) depicts that you are accessing an unassigned property of a string. i.e., `[object Object].first` which becomes `undefined`.

You have to declare the name object in some other scope like `if...else block`, `function block` to achieve what you need.